# ConcurrentDictionary. Потокобезопасность методов расширения

Tags: c#, concurrency, словари

Является ли такое обращение к коллекции и присвоение потокобезопасным?

```
ConcurrentDictionary<Guid,MyObj> dict;

dict.Where(d => d.Key == qual.id).SingleOrDefault().Value.ZONEval=5;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Запросы LINQ к ConcurrentDictionary являются потокобезопасными, но не являются атомарными.

Потокобезопасность означает что вы не получите повреждения структуры, случайных вылетов или некорректных данных. Отсутствие же атомарности означает, что можно получить несогласованные между собой данные: изменение словаря в процессе перечисления может повлиять на перечисление (а может и не повлиять).

Такими свойствами запросы LINQ обладают потому что используют внутри метод `GetEnumerator()`, который, [согласно MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us//library/dd287131(v=vs.110).aspx), является потокобезопасным и возвращает потокобезопасный перечислитель. Про неатомарность перечислителя написано там же:

> The enumerator returned from the dictionary is safe to use concurrently with reads and writes to the dictionary, however it does not represent a moment-in-time snapshot of the dictionary.